# "This webpage has a redirect loop" (redirect website with GeoIP)

Tags: php, redirect, geoip

I'm trying to add some code to my website, in order to redirect users depending on their IP address. Whatever I do I'm getting a "This webpage has a redirect loop" message.

Here's my code:

```
if(isset($_GET['FirstTimer'])){
    setcookie('FirstTimer','something',strtotime('+1 year'),'/');
    $_COOKIE['FirstTimer']='something'; 
}

require_once('geoip.inc');

$gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if(!isset($_COOKIE['FirstTimer'])): 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/'){ 
        switch((string)$country) {
            case 'GR':
                header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/');
                break;
            case 'RU':
                header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/ru');
                break;
            default:
                header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/en');
        }
    }
endif;

geoip_close($gi);
```

The "FirstTimer" cookie is used to determine whether the visitor is a new one or not (because I'd like to redirect new visitors only).

The code is placed on the top of my index.php file, and there are no spaces before '\<\?php ?>' tags.

Comment: Try `die($_COOKIE['FirstTimer']);` directly before the `if(!isset($_COOKIE['FirstTimer'])):` and see if it makes sense

Comment: I tried that, blank page is loaded.

Comment: Nice, so it's empty. Why is your code from Line #1 of your post not properly setting the `$_COOKIE['FirstTimer']`?

Comment: Try `die('<pre>'.print_r($_COOKIE, true).'</pre>');` instead

Comment: I updated my answer. Have a look at it. This is another point of view, because i think you won't have much luck setting a query parameter at first visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `$_GET['FirstTimer']` is not set. So your switch is always executed.

When geoip returns `GR` your script will redirect to `http://mywebsite.com/` again. 
`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns `/` and you are back in your switch again.

There is your loop.

**EDIT**

I've changed your script a little bit. Instead of logging if the user visits the first time, which makes no sense, just log when the user visited the last time.
If this cookie is not set, start geoip and redirect the user. If it is set, update the time.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['last_visit'])) {
    setcookie('last_visit',date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),strtotime('+1 year'),'/');

    require_once('geoip.inc');

    $gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
    $country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/'){ 
        switch((string)$country) {
            case 'GR':
                header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/');
                break;
            case 'RU':
                header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/ru');
                break;
            default:
                header('Location: http://mywebsite.com/en');
        }
    }

    geoip_close($gi);
} else {
    setcookie('last_visit',date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),strtotime('+1 year'),'/');
}
```

But you should definitely enhance this script because what happens, if you have a user that gets on your page with this: `http://yourwebsite.com/great/article/link.html`.
Perhaps you do have a translation for this, but the user won't be redirected.

Comment: You mean that I should remove the 'GR' case completely?

Comment: No, i am assuming that `$_GET['FirstTimer']` is not set at the beginning and your cookie is not created. So check why. And even if it was set, your switch won't be reached.

Comment: I can see now that the problem was the cookie and not redirection. I changed the code by myself based on the comments here and it worked. Your version of code, is better that mine anyway:) Thanks!